# In C how float or double type works exactly?

Tags: c, floating-point, precision, c99

Now I am learning C at university. I fount an unexpected behavior in float type.

This is the example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    float f = 100.0/3;
    printf("%.20f", f);
}
```

The true result is 33.3 (with 3 periodic). I also know that the machine can store only rational numbers and for me is ok, so the answars I expected may be:

- 33.33333**2**00000000000000 (just rounded)

at most

- 33.33333**4**00000000000000 (rounded up)
- 33.33333**2**00000000000000 (rounded down)
- 33.33333**0**00000000000000 (just truncated)

But after executing (compiled with GCC) the result is 33.333332**061767578**00000...

The numbers (**061767578**) after the 2 can't be explained in my mind.

Why this behaviour? I searched a lot, I found nothing :(

Comment: [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)

Comment: It's the closest number to 33.3 (recurring) that can be represented in the floating point format. The rounding takes place in binary, not decimal, so the rounding won't correspond to a single final digit in the decimal representation.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Where did OP specify 754? The tag shouldn't be there.

Comment: @2501: They don't know what it's called, but it's what the question is about.

Comment: @samgak thank you very much, now it's clear :D

Comment: They're not stored in base 10, so you shouldn't expect anything ending in 000000

Comment: The question is about floating point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the exact value that is stored, you should print more than 20 digits. The number should end with `75000…` or `25000…`.

Assuming you are using an implementation of IEEE 754, each `float` is of the form `num / den`, where `num` has 24 binary(!) digits and `den` is a power of 2. (Except for denormalized numbers, but that's another topic.)

Comment: Off by 1: where `num` has 24 binary digits.  (23 expressly encoded, 1 implied)  [Significand precision: 24 bits (23 explicitly stored)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32)